# How to call the current anonymous function in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an anonymous function which is supposed to call itself. However, I have no variable or function name at hand, so I was hoping to find a function that could do return "this" in context of functions. Is there such a thing?

Here's an example:

```
$f = function() use($bar, $foo) {
  // call this function again.
};
```

Calling like this:

```
call_user_func(__FUNCTION__);
```

Leads to this:

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function '{closure}' not found or invalid function name

If I try to put $f in the use-list, then it says the variable is not defined (because it is not yet).

Comment: __FUNCTION__();
See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php.

Comment: stop downvoting the answers, your original question didn't mention anonymous function anywhere. You should give them time to edit or delete.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions

Comment: @Esailija I'm not down voting anything. I wish there was a way to see the down voters.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`__FUNCTION__` cannot be used in anonymous functions

Pass the variable holding the anonymous function as a reference in the 'use' clause....

```
$f = function() use($bar, $foo, &$f) {
   $f();
};
```

Tip of the hat to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions).

Comment: You may as well just call the function `f`.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions One can `unset()` a lambda, not so a function definition.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I found out the way to do this:

```
$f = function() use(&$f) {
  $f();
};

$f();
```

The key thing is to pass $f as a reference. Thus PHP does not try to pass a value but a reference to a memory slot.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Answer (score 0):

> I have an anonymous function which is supposed to call itself.

I prefer to use `call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $params);` when calling a recursive function.

As your example doesn't have any arguments then i guess `call_user_func(__FUNCTION__);` would be better suited.

You would expect and hope the following code would work but that would be too easy.

```
$bar = 10;
$foo = 0;

$f = function() use (&$bar,$foo) {

    if($bar){ // condition needed to prevent infinite loop
        echo $bar-- . PHP_EOL;
        call_user_func(__FUNCTION__); // wont work
    }
};
$f();
```

The `__FUNCTION__` ["Magic constant"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is unavailable to closures so the code needs to be adapted to allow the passing of the function variable. we can make the function available by passing it as a regular argument or via the `use` statement.

Function passed as argument

```
$bar = 10;
$foo = 0;

$f = function( $__FUNCTION__ = null ) use (&$bar, $foo) {

    if($__FUNCTION__ && $bar){
        echo $bar-- . PHP_EOL;
        call_user_func( $__FUNCTION__, $__FUNCTION__);
    }
};
$f ( $f );
```

Function passed via `use` statement

```
$bar = 10;
$foo = 0;

$__FUNCTION__ = function() use (&$bar, $foo, &$__FUNCTION__) {

    if($bar){
        echo $bar-- . PHP_EOL;
        call_user_func( $__FUNCTION__ );
    }
};
$__FUNCTION__();
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/3Hhq36), click edit-> <kbd>ideone it!</kbd> to re-run code.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Edit: Posted before code was given. Of course it doesn't work on anonymous functions.

```
call_user_func(__FUNCTION__, $param1, $param2);
call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $params);
```

Comment: Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '{closure}' not found or invalid function name

Answer (score -4):

```
function i_dont_know() {
    call_user_func(__FUNCTION__,$params);
 //or
    $funcname = __FUNCTION__;
    $funcname($params);


}
```