# Using current variable function inside the function

Tags: php, closures

i need to recursively call a variable function, how can i do this?

```
$rec = function($li) use($html,$rec) { // error, rec was not defined yet
   if( ... ) $rec( ... ); 
}
```

how can i do this?

Comment: can you post your whole function? Because `use` is used for using namespaces and you used after `function`.

Comment: http://pastie.org/6418447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function variable `$rec` by reference (`&$rec`) so you can set it to the function then. This will also define it.

```
use($html, &$rec) 
           ^
```

You find this principle outlined in the [question *Anonymous recursive PHP functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions).