# PHP - Assign an anonymous function to a variable inside of its own function and use it

Tags: php, function, php-7, php-7.0

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function func() {

    $call = function() {
        ...
    };

    $call();

}
```

But it's throwing an error saying:

> Function name must be a string

I also tried calling the function like this:

```
$this->call();
call(); // and like this
```

And it's not working as well.

Is there a reason why I can't do what I'm doing?

**EDIT**

> It seems to be a problem with the original code, and not in the example I wrote

This is my real code:

```
$data = [...];
$menu_array = [];
$getChildren = function($id) {
          $children = [];
          foreach ($data as $node) {
              if ($id == $node["parent"]) {
                  array_push($children, $node);
              }
          } 
          return empty($children) ? null : $children;
        };

        $check = function($arr, $dat) {
            foreach ($dat as $node) {
                $children = $getChildren($node["id"]);
                if ($children == null) {
                    $arr[$node["display_name"]] = $node["model"];
                } else {
                    $arr[$node["display_name"]][] = $children;
                    $check($children);
                }
            }
        };
$check($menu_array, $data);
```

The error is thrown in this line:

```
$children = $getChildren($node["id"]);
```

Comment: Look at the line number in error.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It [works](https://imgur.com/a/4VAJbSl) on my computer (php 7.2.4)

Comment: @revo The line number is where $call() is at.

Comment: @Cid Doesn't work on debian with PHP 7.0.33

Comment: It's still working on windows 10 with php 7.0.29

Comment: Can you share the exact code you are running and the exact error message?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure you are executing the correct version of php?

Comment: Are you using this in web application or console? if CLI, php path might be the wrong one and use the 5.x version

Comment: @NicoHaase Updated the post with my original code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: @FightRay I haven't given your post a single down vote because I think that this is an interesting question. But the other question provides some background of the technical difficulties you are facing, and it clearly tells you about the possibilities to use `use`. So please don't be rude

Comment: @NicoHaase Yeah that may be helpful but you're going as far as to call it a duplicate, when it's not even the same question. You can't even find it by searching for my question. It's a completely different case... that's why I think saying possible duplicate is rude. If you think it's an interesting question, you should not call it a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anonymous recursive PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do here, is recursion!
The problem is, that PHP does not automatically add any variables from the outer scope, into the function scope. In your code `$check($children);`, the variable `$check` is actually not defined.

You can fix this by telling PHP that it should use the `$getChildren` and `$check` variable from outside the function:

```
$getChildren = function($id) use (&$getChildren) {
   ...
```

and

```
$check = function($arr, $dat) use (&$check, &$getChildren) {
  ...
```

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480242/2681964

Comment: Great answer, thank you.

Comment: @FightRay If it worked out, could you mark this as accepted answer? That helps my reputation, you reputation and the fact that this worked for you for people that come here later :)

Comment: Yeah of course, I did it. And the other question someone claimed is a possible duplicate is not even close to similar to mine... I think my question was helpful since I couldn't find any turn of events of the sort in google and I explained my issue pretty well.