# Cannot convert a recursive function into an IIFE

Tags: php, recursion, iife

I have a code that contains a recursive function like this:

```php
<?php

$arr = [];

function recursive(&$argument)
{
    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        recursive($argument);
    }
}
recursive($arr);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

That works fine. But errors start to appear after I converted the recursive function into an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) like this:

```php
$recursive = (function (&$argument)
{
    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        $recursive($argument);    // line 10
    }
})($arr);
```

The errors are:

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: recursive in *php_file_path* on line 10
>
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in *php_file_path*:10
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 *php_file_path*(12): {closure}(Array)
>
> #1 {main}
>
> thrown in *php_file_path* on line 10

I thought it might be that the function needs the variable which references itself, so I added the keyword `use` like the following one. But the errors of the result are no difference except for the notice of undefined variable now points to line 5.

```php
$recursive = (function (&$argument) use ($recursive)    // line 5
{
    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        $recursive($argument);
    }
})($arr);
```

Please note that the code is just an example simply for illustration's sake.

Comment: This can't work like that. `$recursive` (would) eventually get the result of calling the function, not the function itself.

Comment: @tkausl Sorry, but I failed to understand it. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes. It's an example simply for illustration's sake. I just added that note at the bottom my question.

Comment: Whatever benefit there is in an IIFE is probably particular to the language you're trying to port this from, and not PHP. Just do regular recursion.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anonymous-recursive-function-in-php/

Comment: The purpose is certainly not wanting to add the function definition to the global scope and just want things to execute.

Comment: Relevant [Anonymous recursive PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2480179/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve here, but you can make what you are trying to do work using the `global` statement to define `$recursive` within the function:

```
$arr = array();
($recursive = function (&$argument)
{
    global $recursive;

    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        $recursive($argument);    // line 10
    }
})($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => foo
    [2] => foo
    [3] => foo
    [4] => foo
    [5] => foo
    [6] => foo
    [7] => foo
    [8] => foo
    [9] => foo
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/A67qG)

Note the need to define `$arr` as an empty array before invocation, otherwise `count` fails. If you don't want to do that, you need to include an `if (empty($arr))` check in the function.

Note also that `$recursive` is available to the rest of the code after this statement e.g.

```
$arr2 = array();
$recursive($arr2);
```

This is a more traditional PHP style of doing this:

```
$recursive = function (&$argument)
{
    global $recursive;

    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        $recursive($argument);    // line 10
    }
};
$arr = array();
$recursive($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output is the same. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/USGFD)

**Update**

On looking at this further it is apparent that you can make this work with `use`, not `global`, by using `&$recursive` in the `use` expression, making it a reference rather than an immediate value. For example:

```
$arr = array();
($recursive = function (&$argument) use (&$recursive)
{
    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        $recursive($argument);    // line 10
    }
})($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

or

```
$recursive = function (&$argument) use (&$recursive)
{
    if (count($argument) < 10)
    {
        $argument[] = 'foo';
        $recursive($argument);    // line 10
    }
};
$arr = array();
$recursive($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/As0kH)

Comment: @IanY. having thought about it more I realise you can use `use` rather than `global`, it's just necessary to use a reference to `$recursive` rather than attempting to use the immediate value.