# How to build an anonymous recursive function in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, anonymous-function

EDIT: I'm sorry for the duplicate, but searching for the title of this question wasn't showing such duplicate in the search result, so I was not aware there is question, already.

---

This won't work, because `$greet` is unknown by the time it will be called.

```php
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
    if($name != 'PHP')
    {
        $greet('PHP'); // $greet not defined
    }
};

$greet('World');
?>
```

The idea is to have a recursive function that is purely in its parent scope (i.e. function in function), without the requirement to build a class.

So, how to build an anonymous recursive function in PHP, properly? Is it even possible? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anonymous recursive PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions)

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes, thanks a lot. It wasn't showing up when searching for it using the title of this question.

Comment: Small tip: Google search works better for queries constructed as a sentence (copy and paste your question title into it and you'll see). For the internal SO search, it's better to only input the keywords (e.g. `[php] anonymous recursive function`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to `use` the `$greet` variable by reference, like this:

```
$greet = function($name) use (&$greet)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
    if($name != 'PHP')
    {
        $greet('PHP');
    }
};

$greet('World');
```

Working example:
https://3v4l.org/vUhIW

This article describes this a bit more:
https://fragdev.com/blog/php-recursion-with-anonymous-functions